# Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the request.security function

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I've written a code in order to find a specific situation as shown below;
(if a crossover/crossunder of 2 situations were true in 15mintues candles, then find candles with the same situation in 5 minutes.

here's the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title=" TRY ___???", overlay=true)

//StochRSI

smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
//plot(k, "K", color=#2962FF)
//plot(d, "D", color=#FF6D00)
//h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
//h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
//fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")

//FISHER

len = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length")
high_ = ta.highest(hl2, len)
low_ = ta.lowest(hl2, len)
round_(val) => val > .99 ? .999 : val < -.99 ? -.999 : val
value = 0.0
value := round_(.66 * ((hl2 - low_) / (high_ - low_) - .5) + .67 * nz(value[1]))
fish1 = 0.0
fish1 := .5 * math.log((1 + value) / (1 - value)) + .5 * nz(fish1[1])
fish2 = fish1[1]
//hline(1.5, "1.5", color=#E91E63)
//hline(0.75,"0.75", color=#787B86)
//hline(0, "0", color=#E91E63)
//hline(-0.75, "-0.75", color=#787B86)
//hline(-1.5, "-1.5", color=#E91E63)
//plot(fish1, color=#2962FF, title="Fisher")
//plot(fish2, color=#FF6D00, title="Trigger")


//BUY
[fish1_15,fish2_15] = request.security('','15',[fish1,fish2])
[k_15,d_15] = request.security('','15',[k,d])

[fish1_5,fish2_5] = request.security('','5',[fish1,fish2])
[k_5,d_5] = request.security('','5',[k,d])

buy_signal = if ta.crossover(fish1_15,fish2_15) and ta.crossover(k_15,d_15)
    ta.crossover(fish1_5,fish2_5) and ta.crossover(k_5,d_5)
else
    false
plotshape(buy_signal, style= shape.labelup, location= location.belowbar ,color= color.green,  textcolor= color.white, text = "buy" )

//SELL

sell_signal = if ta.crossunder(fish1_15,fish2_15) and ta.crossunder(k_15,d_15)
    ta.crossunder(fish1_5,fish2_5) and ta.crossunder(k_5,d_5)
else
    false
plotshape(sell_signal, style= shape.labeldown, location= location.abovebar ,color= color.red,  textcolor= color.white, text = "sell" )
```

and here's the error:
//line 41: Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the request.security function.

I would like to know if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines

```
value = 0.0
value := round_(.66 * ((hl2 - low_) / (high_ - low_) - .5) + .67 * nz(value[1]))
fish1 = 0.0
fish1 := .5 * math.log((1 + value) / (1 - value)) + .5 * nz(fish1[1])
fish2 = fish1[1]
```

are logically incorrect.
Probably you're meant to code it like this:

```
v1 = round_(.66 * ((hl2 - low_) / (high_ - low_) - .5) + .67) 
value = v1 * nz(v1[1])
f1 = .5 * math.log((1 + value) / (1 - value)) + .5
fish1 = f1 * nz(f1[1])
fish2 = fish1[1]
```

As for the error, variables which have been first declared, then reassigned using :=, are called  [mutable variables](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#reassignement-operator).
Mutable variable may be changed inside any scope of the script.
The `security` function creates another chart scope, 'sucking' inside all of the declared variables from the script. It cannot 'suck' mutable variables, because they values can be changed somewhere else.